# To bold one line with Perl regex

Tags: regular-expression, perl

I have

```
1. Lorem
He he he

% not sure spelling
2. Lorem 
ipsun
```

I want to have

```
\textbf{1. Lorem}
He he he

% not sure spelling
\textbf{2. Lorem}
ipsun
```

My pseudocode attempt

```
perl -000pe 's/\n\n\d./; s/\n\d.\n\\textbf\{ /g; s/$/\}/'
```

which is based on my two previous questions about regex here.
I try to match the thing which starts with a number.
Replace the beginning of the match and the end of the match.

The code gives me

```
Backslash found where operator expected at -e line 1, near "s/\n\n\d./; s/\"
Backslash found where operator expected at -e line 1, near "n\"
Backslash found where operator expected at -e line 1, near "n\"
Backslash found where operator expected at -e line 1, near "textbf\"
Backslash found where operator expected at -e line 1, near "$/\"
    (Missing operator before \?)
syntax error at -e line 1, near "s/\n\n\d./; s/\"
Execution of -e aborted due to compilation errors.
```

**How can you bold the given text?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the `-000` makes each "paragraph" into a "line", you can use the classic regular expression anchors (`^` and `$`) to match the beginning and end of each "line". So, in your case, all you need is:

```
$ perl -000pe 's/^(.+)\n/\\textbf{$1}\n/;' file 
\textbf{1. Lorem}
He he he

\textbf{2. Lorem }
ipsun
```

Note that the `\` needs to be escaped (`\\`), that's because `\` is a special character used to escape others so you also need to use it to escape itself.

---

If you can have comments as the first line of a paragraph, then this approach fails and you need to bold all lines that start with a number:

```
perl -pe 's/^\d\..+/\\textbf{$&}/' file
```

Comment: I changed the data little more challenging with an initiating comment mark. See above. Can you edit your command to work with it? I think the first match is little different only. Otherwise, the same.

Comment: @Masi sure, done.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$ perl -ple '$_ = "\\textbf{$_}" if /^\d/' cat2
\textbf{1. Lorem}
He he he

\textbf{2. Lorem}
ipsun
```

Answer (score 1):

I used the `-0777` option which loads the whole file into memory at once. Then, you can replace newlines:

```
perl -0777 -pe 's/\n(\d\..*)/\n\\textbf{$1}/g'
```